# ROWNUM truncating output recordset

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, rownum

This query

```
select id from TABLE where id=1234 or id like '234%'
```

returns 11 rows, as expected. But when i try this

```
select rownum as rnum, id from TABLE where id=1234 or id like '234%'
```

or even this

```
select * from (
     select id from TABLE where id=1234 or id like '234%'
) where rownum < 22
```

I have only 10 rows (id=`1234` is missing in the output recordset). Why is that?

**DDL for Table TABLE**

```
  CREATE TABLE "TABLE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(28,0), 
    "SPOT_LCK" NUMBER(28,0), 
    "STATUS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "CARRIER_YN" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    ...
    "DRIVER" NUMBER(38,0) DEFAULT 0
   );
```

**Constraints for Table TABLE**

```
ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_TBL" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
```

**Oracle 12c Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit**

Comment: use <= 22 to fetch 22 rows
you gave id=1234 or like 234%
in this case how you can expect id 123?

Comment: Why would id 123 be returned by what `where` clause, in any of those queries? If the first one *was* returning 123 then something would be wrong with that, but the others are right. If you're really sure it is doing that then copy-and-paste the query you run and the IDs you get back into your question. It's more likely you aren't running quite what you think...

Comment: Please show us the structure of the table, best is the create statement. You treat `id`as a `NUMBER` and as a `VARCHAR2` in the where clause, so we cannot answer your question properly without knowing your structure. Next, we need some example data to understand / replay your data question. Best again as insert statement as @ewramner has done. If you don't show the data, people are guessing and typing in your data, which costs valuable time...

Comment: 2 @Alex Poole
i didn't understand why you are referring to 123. In the original query ID=1234, not 123. (i must have made a mistake, and moderators fixed it, right now question has no errors, so it is 1234 that i am expecting in the output recordset, not 123)
And i am copy-pasting the query and it is not working.

Comment: 2 @Gaj
i tried with <= still doesn't work

Comment: @user2858200 - your question said 123 was missing until David edited it; you can see that in the revision history. Even so, this doesn't seem to be reproducible, with a CTE or a real table. If you include your full table DDL and full Oracle version and patch level in the question it *might* give a clue, but at the moment what you're describing sounds impossible. (There are always bugs, of course...)

Comment: I still can't reproduce in 12.1.0.2 or 12.2.0.1. As you still haven't given us your version number I'm going to guess you're on an unpatched 12.1.0.1 and are hitting a bug; there seem to have been a couple in the first version of 12c. Look on MoS, or raise a service request, or patch; although if you are on that version that might suggest you don't have a support contract.  Without the same version to reproduce/test on my only suggestion is to use `row_number()` instead.

Comment: @Alex Poole
yes. i guess i have misstyped 1234 in the beginning. Thanks to the moderators.
Added DB version, i.e. Oracle 12c Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your results, you must have made a mistake. Minimal example:

```
create table testrn ( id number primary key, c1 number );
insert into testrn values (1234, 1);
insert into testrn values (2341, 2);
insert into testrn values (2342, 3);
insert into testrn values (2343, 4);
insert into testrn values (2344, 5);
insert into testrn values (2345, 6);
insert into testrn values (2346, 7);
insert into testrn values (2347, 8);
insert into testrn values (2348, 9);
insert into testrn values (2349, 10);
insert into testrn values (23410, 11);
commit;
select id, rownum from testrn where id=1234 or id like '234%';
```

This returns 11 rows as expected. And I assume that you meant 1234 is missing as 123 is not used in the SQL?

Comment: if i make similar query it works (or with dual table), but with given table and given query (in the topic) it is not. query itself is valid 100%
.
.
_>And I assume that you meant 1234 is missing as 123 is not used in the SQL?_
what i meant, was 1234 is not in the output recordset, whereas it should be

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution found as of now: oracle says latest patch required, app vendor says they don't support it. so we're leaving as it is.